# How to automate generation of SVG file with Graphviz?

Tags: svg, build-process, graphviz, github-pages

I decided to start a project which is essentially a website. This website will be published through Github Pages.

My website will include an SVG file. The SVG file is generated by Graphviz from a DOT-file. The idea is that to modify the information displayed in the SVG, users can change the definition of the DOT-file, then Graphviz will re-generate the SVG, and the new SVG image will automatically be displayed once the web page is served.

However, I am left in the uncomfortable situation of requiring contributors who edit the DOT-file to run a script that calls Graphviz, and then commit changes to both the SVG *and* the DOT file.

If a contributor changes the DOT-file, but forgets to run the Graphviz script, then commits, the repository will contain a DOT-file and an SVG which are inconsistent with each other.

I can't not track versions of the DOT-file, because the SVG is gibberish - the DOT-file is the human-editable definition. I can't not track the SVG, because, how else will it stay up to date and available to Github Pages for consumption? And yet, with both of them tracked, I am essentially keeping track of changes in a redundant manner, and introducing opportunity for conflicts. It's a bit like versioning both your C code *and* the compiled .exe. Which is silly.

What's the best way of making sure that whenever the DOT-file is edited, the SVG will stay concurrent with it? Do I need to seriously rethink my strategy?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider setting up a Jenkins instance to do this. Create a job that is triggered by a change in the dot file (using the git plugin). The job would execute the dot command and then commit the new svg file.

Comment: In this case, you would still be committing the SVG file to the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Generated files **should not by committed** to your repository.

By default, [GitHub Pages](https://guides.github.com/features/pages) uses Jekyll to create sites.

If you are using this workflow, then I would suggest taking a look at writing/using a [Jekyll Generator](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/generators) plugin to dynamically create this SVG from your DOT-file.